# Woocommerce - Force user set address to register in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need need that users set their adress when they are going to register.

Any plugin?

Woocommerce - Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a address form when registering out the box, only Email and Password.

You'll need to custom code or use a plugin to add the address fields in the first place, rather than make those fields required.

Comment: How to do it via code: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-woocommerce-registration-form-fields/